# Jenkins - ssh credentials and editing credentials issues

Tags: ssh, git, jenkins, bitbucket.org

## Can't connect to bitbucket through ssh in Jenkins

I can get it to work using https and providing my bitbucket account password, butI can't get it to work using an ssh key and ssh passphrase. I have generated a new key using `ssh-keygen` then copied **id_rsa.pub** to **bitbucket** and **id_rsa** to **Jenkins** credentials along with my username and the *passphrase used* when generating the key.

In addition, I don't see how to change the credentials once created, so I have quite the list piling up as I try to make changes to find out what's wrong.

Your guidance in this matter is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: still require help